# in Linux: merge two very big files

Tags: linux, merge, bigdata

I would like to merge two files (one is space delimited and the other tab delimited) keeping only the records that are matching between the two files:

File 1: space delimited

```
A B C D E F G H
s e id_234 4 t 5 7 9
r d id_45 6 h 3 9 10
f w id_56 2 y 7 3 0
s f id_67 2 y 10 3 0
```

File 2: tab delimited

```
I L M N O P
s e 4 u id_67 88
d a 5 d id_33 67
g r 1 o id_45 89
```

I would like to match File 1 field 3 ("C") with file 2 field 5 ("O"), and merge the files like this:

File 3: tab delimited

```
I L M N O P A B D E F G H
s e 4 u id_67 88 s f 2 y 10 3 0
g r 1 o id_45 89 r d 6 h 3 9 10
```

There are entries in file 1 that don't appear in file 2, and vice versa, but I only want to keep the intersection (the common ids).

I don't really care about the order.

I would prefer not to use join because these are really big unsorted files and join requires  to sort by common field before, which takes a very long time and much memory.

I have tried with awk but unsuccessfully

```
awk > file3 'NR == FNR {
  f2[$3] = $2; next 
}
$5 in f2 {
 print $0, f2[$2]
}' file2 file1
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. you'll ideally be looking to avoid an n^2 solution which is what the awk based approach seems to require. For each record in file1 you have to scan file2 to see if occurs. That's where the time is going.

I'd suggest writing a python (or similar) script for this and building a map id->file position for one of the files and then querying that whilst scanning the other file. That'd get you an nlogn runtime which, to me at least, looks to be the best you could do here (using a hash for the index leaves you with the expensive problem of seeking to the file pos).

In fact, here's the Python script to do that:

```
f1 = file("file1.txt")

f1_index = {}

# Generate index for file1
fpos = f1.tell()
line = f1.readline()
while line:
    id = line.split()[2]
    f1_index[id] = fpos
    fpos = f1.tell()
    line = f1.readline()

# Now scan file2 and output matches
f2 = file("file2.txt")
line = f2.readline()
while line:
    id = line.split()[4]
    if id in f1_index:
        # Found a matching line, seek to file1 pos and read
        # the line back in
        f1.seek(f1_index[id], 0)
        line2 = f1.readline().split()
        del line2[2] # <- Remove the redundant id_XX
        new_line = "\t".join(line.strip().split() + line2)
        print new_line
    line = f2.readline()
```

Comment: Thank you very much tobe. Python seems too slow since the files are very big: it takes about 10 minutes to run the script you wrote (thanks for this anyway). I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this? Would Bash be the same?

Comment: After trying other Linux commands tobe's solution to do this in Python seems to be the best. I am just getting to know Python now and I am having a very basic issue now: I get the merged files I think (I guess it doesn't matter if one is tab and the other space delimited), but the headers disappear. Is there a way to retain the headers from the two files? Thank you again!

Comment: If by headers you mean "I L M N O P A B D E F G H" then simply add: print "I L M N O P A B D E F G H" to the top of the script. As regarding speeding this up... it's all about maxing out the I/O subsystem, the current solution is non-optimal in this respect since it's stop/starting at each readline.

Answer (score 0):

If sorting the two files (on the columns you want to match on) is a possibility (and wouldn't break the content somehow), `join` is probably a better approach than trying to accomplish this with `bash` or `awk`. Since you state you don't really care about the order, then this would probably be an appropriate method.

It would look something like this:

join -1 3 -2 5 -o '2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,1.1,1.2,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8' <(sort -k3,3 file1) <(sort -k5,5 file2)

I wish there was a better way to tell it which columns to output, because that's a lot of typing, but that's the way it works. You could probably also leave off the `-o ...` stuff, and then just post-process the output with `awk` or something to get it into the order you want...

Comment: Hi twalberg, thank you, I would prefer to avoid "join" as I said in the question because they are huge unsorted files and if i use join I would have to sort them and it takes too long… I was hoping there could be a fast alternative?